# Paint some days in calendar

Tags: python, tkinter, calendar

I created a program which display a calendar. I'm using tkinter and Calendar imports. 
Is it possible to paint the number or backgroud (actually mark anyhow) of all Sunday days?

[image: Current GUI]

Comment: Is it a `Text` widget where you display your calendar? If so you can change the color of the particular text by applying tags.

Comment: Yes It is. Here is the code where I define the widget for print calendar:

self.area = Text(self.master,font=('Courier New', 20, "bold"),width=20, height=8,bd=15)

             self.area.pack()

Can you please tell me something more about tags?

Comment: More importantly is how you inserted the text for your calendar.

Comment: Sorry, okey, I use a function "calendar.month(y, m, 2, 1)"

Comment: Without knowing how you're drawing the calendar, it's impossible for us to give good advice. The literal answer to "is it possible" is yes, but whether it's easy or not depends on how your code is written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments you can use a tag to mark Sundays. You use `calendar.month(year, month, 2, 1)` to display the calendar so your columns are two character wide and separated by a space, therefore the Sunday column starts at character 18.
The first line is the month name, the second the week days so you need to start adding the tag at line 3.

Here is the code:

```
import calendar
from tkinter import Text

text = Text()
text.pack()
# configure tag to change the background and foreground of sundays
text.tag_configure("sunday", background='light grey', foreground='red')

# display calendar
month = calendar.month(2020, 2, 2, 1)
text.insert('1.0', month)

# add the sunday tag to sundays
for line in range(3, len(month.splitlines()) + 1):
    text.tag_add('sunday', f"{line}.18", f"{line}.20")
```

[image: screenshot]

By the way, if you want your calendar to be well aligned with straight columns, like in my screenshot, you need to use a monospaced font.

Comment: This is exactely what I need. But now I have ea problem with implementing this into my code. Can you give me a help. There is my code:

Comment: This is exactely what I need. But now I have ea problem with implementing this into my code. Can you give me a help. There is my code: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/9eeddabea1783781e896afb5560dc46120200205205425/068fe0

Comment: Replace `text` in my code by `self.area`, the `.tag_configure(...)` part goes in the `widgets()` method below the line were you create the text widget. The for loop to add the `sunday` tag goes at the end of `getCal()` except that I called `month` what you call `cal`. By the way, the first index of a Text widget is `"1.0"` not `0.0`.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I did it :D

Answer (score 2):

If you use `tkcalendar` library, then you have an option of configuring the `background` and `forground` color of the weekend days.

A weekend consists of a **Saturday** and the **Sunday**. *That means you cannot configure only the `Sundays` instead both days*.

The following properties are configured:

- `weekendbackground` - To configure the background color of the
  weekend days.
- `weekendforeground` - To configure the foreground color of the
  weekend days.

**A simple working code:**

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkcalendar

root = tk.Tk()

cal = tkcalendar.Calendar(root, selectmode='day', year=2020, month=1, day=1)
cal.config(weekendbackground='blue', weekendforeground='white')
cal.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

If you want to use default colors, then you can remove the use of these properties.

You can read more about `tkcalendar` in this link - https://pypi.org/project/tkcalendar/

Hope it helps!